# Regular expression to validate a string starts with a char and contains allowed chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with my regular expression written in javascript.
I have tried using the regularExpression generator online, and the best i can come up with is the this:

```
^[a-z.-]{0,50}$
```

The expression must validate the following

- String first char MUST start with a-z (no alpha)
- String can contain any char in range a-z (no alpha), 0-9 and the characters dash "-" and dot "."
- String can be of max length 50 chars

Examples of success strings

- username1
- username.lastname
- username-anotherstring1
- this.is.also.ok

No good strings

- 1badusername
- .verbad
- -bad
- also very bad has spaces

// Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost (assuming "no alpha" means no uppercase letters)

https://regex101.com/r/O9hvLP/3

```
^[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9\.-]{0,49}$
```

The {1} is optional, I put it there for descriptive reasons

Comment: Shouldnt 1-49 be 0-49? Otherwise the OP "can contain" on bullet point 2  would be "must contain"

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks - I was focused on not exceeding 50

Answer (score 3):

I think this should cover what you want

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9.-]{0,49}$
```

That is starts `a-z` but then has 0-49 of `a-z`, `0-9` or `.-`

Live example: https://regexr.com/5k8eu

Edit: Not sure if you intended to allow upper and lowercase, but if you did both character classes could add `A-Z` as well!

Comment: Ah, you have a different order than I did. SO -0-9 does not work but 0-9.- does

Answer (score 2):

If the `.` and `-` can not be at the end, and there can not be consecutive ones, another option could be:

```
^[a-z](?=[a-z0-9.-]{0,49}$)[a-z0-9]*(?:[.-][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z]` Match a single char a-z
- `(?=[a-z0-9.-]{0,49}$)` Assert 0-49 chars to the right to the end of string
- `[a-z0-9]*` Match optional chars a-z0-9
- `(?:[.-][a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally match either `.` or `-` and 1+ times a char a-z0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wqVUbJ/1)